# How to prevent line breaks in list items using CSS

Tags: html, css, word-wrap

I'm trying to put a link called *Submit resume* in a menu using a `li` tag. Because of the whitespace between the two words it wraps to two lines. How to prevent this wrapping with CSS?

Answer (score 1111, accepted):

Use `white-space: nowrap;`<sup>[[1]](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#white-space-property) [[2]](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)</sup> or give that link more space by setting `li`'s width to greater values.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> [§ 3. White Space and Wrapping: the white-space property - W3 CSS Text Module Level 3](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#white-space-property) 
<sup>[2]</sup> [white-space - CSS: Cascading Style Sheets | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space)

Comment: I prevented line break in li items using `display: inline;`. Maybe this will also help others with similar problems.

Comment: Its important to be careful with display: inline as it can have side effects.  white-space: nowrap; has only the one effect.

Comment: In this case text overflow happens. how to prevent that?

Answer (score 190):

You could add this little snippet of code to add a nice "…" to the ending of the line if the content is to large to fit on one line:

```css
li {
  overflow: hidden; 
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  white-space: nowrap;
}
```

Comment: I was looking for a text clamping solution, but I'll stick to this solution

Answer (score 38):

If you want to achieve this selectively (ie: only to that particular link), you can use a non-breaking space instead of a normal space:

```
<li>submit&nbsp;resume</li>
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-breaking_space#Encodings

*edit: I understand that this is HTML, not CSS as requested by the OP, but some may find it helpful…*

Answer (score 21):

`display: inline-block;` will prevent break between the words in a list item:

```css
li {
  display: inline-block;
}
```

Comment: If I click through to the jsfiddle and adjust the width of the output, the individual list items break between the word "list" and the number, which is exactly what the OP *doesn't* want...

Answer (score 5):

Bootstrap 4 has a class named `text-nowrap`. It is just what you need.

Comment: I'd prefer to avoid recommend using Bootstrap in 2019.

Comment: @BrodaNoel Why?

Comment: @YevgeniyAfanasyev It's bloat

Answer (score 3):

In your CSS, **white-space** can do the job

*possible values:*

```
white-space: nowrap
white-space: pre
white-space: pre-wrap
white-space: pre-line
white-space: break-spaces
white-space: normal
```

Comment: I think `white-space: nowrap` should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

`<nobr>your text</nobr>` (not css but easier in some cases)

Comment: Depreciated - not recommended. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/nobr