# Text wrap breaking on mobile

Tags: html, css

Below is a screenshot of the responsive mobile display of the wrapped text that breaks on a longer word. Is there any way to avoid this break? I would be OK if it simply starting the text below the ad on mobile. I just want to avoid the break in text.

[image]

The HTML I currently use in Wordpress is:

```
    <div style="padding-right:10px; float: left;"><scriptcode></script></div> Text here
```

Comment: This question is too broad and very case specific, you should consider learning better html/css fundamentals

Answer (score 1):

I went with this solution from [here](https://justmarkup.com/log/2015/07/dealing-with-long-words-in-css/).

```
    p {
      overflow-wrap: break-word;
      word-wrap: break-word;
      -webkit-hyphens: auto;
      -ms-hyphens: auto;
      -moz-hyphens: auto;
      hyphens: auto;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add `clear: left` to that paragraph to go under anything floated which is above/before it.

Comment: Would this impact things on mobile and desktop? I'm aiming for a solution that leaves things as-is on desktop (wraps fine around ad), while avoiding the break issue on responsive.

Comment: I don't think so - this simply prevents that this text floats around floated elements which are earlier in the code. That would typically only apply to floated images inside the text paragraphs.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a duplicate of [How to prevent line breaks in list items using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383143/how-to-prevent-line-breaks-in-list-items-using-css)

See this article for more detail: https://www.w3.org/TR/css-text-3/#white-space

Here's what I'd try to play with and see the effects in your browser:

```
<style>
.wrap_like_normal{
    font-size: 3rem;
}
.nowrap_ad {
    font-size: 3rem;
    white-space: nowrap;
}
</style>
<p class="nowrap_ad">
    This isn't gonna be wrapped at all. This isn't gonna be wrapped at all. This isn't gonna be wrapped at all. This isn't gonna be wrapped at all.
</p >
<p class="wrap_like_normal">
    Wrap this all you want. Wrap this all you want. Wrap this all you want. Wrap this all you want.
</p>
```