# Responsive text, how to enable scroll instead of next/new line?

Tags: html, css

How do I style the text so that in smaller screens it will stay as a single line and the omitted text is viewable via scroll? I use foundation framework and grid-container.

Reddit has this effect where the details of the post is scrollable then the message is within the box.

Comment: please share you code snippet. thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of : https://stackoverflow.com/q/1383143/8620333

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to prevent line breaks in list items using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383143/how-to-prevent-line-breaks-in-list-items-using-css)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the CSS overflow property,

```
div.ex1 {
  overflow: scroll;
}
```

Learn more [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp)

Comment: `overflow-x: auto` would be better. And, just to be sure: `white-space: nowrap;`