# I want to fix flex items while window resize

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to keep flex items while window resize...please help me...
I used min-width, but it didn't work well....
what's wrong with me ?

```css
.sticky2 {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 100;
  min-width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0;
  /* flex-wrap: nowrap; */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

  h2 {
  display: inline-block;
}

header {
  position: relative;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  /* flex-wrap: nowrap; */
  /* max-width: 1384px;
  min-width: 1014px; */
  /* height: 100%; */
  margin: 0 auto;
  /* z-index: 200; */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  /* margin-top: 50px; */
  background-color: rgb(102, 185, 102);
  transition: 0.6s;
  /* padding: 5px 0; */
  padding: 10px 0;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
/*  */
/*header 높낮이 패딩을 주니까 scroll 길이가 맞네*/
/*  */

header.sticky {
  background-color: #fff;
  padding: 20px 0;
  /* min-width: 100%; */
  /* height: 50px; */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}
header h1 {
  padding-left: 160px;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.d {
  padding-right: 180px;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-1 {
  margin-right: 30px;
  border-radius: 20px;
  padding: 8px 15px;
  background-color: rgb(171, 235, 171);
  cursor: pointer;
  font-weight: 700;
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-1,
.header-2,
.header__logo {
  min-width: 0;
  min-height: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.header-1:hover {
  background-color: hotpink;
  transition: all 0.9s;
}
```

```html
<div class="sticky2">
  <header class="sticky">
    <h1 class="header__logo">world pet</h1>
    <div class="d">
      <span class="header-1">reservation</span
      ><span class="header-2">ask</span>
    </div>
  </header>
</div>
```

How to keep flex items when window resize ?

Comment: Would you mind explain more about what you expect to see? What is the expected result?

Comment: You want to keep "world pet", "reservations" and "Ask" in same line even if resizing browser, right?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to prevent line breaks in list items using CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1383143/how-to-prevent-line-breaks-in-list-items-using-css)